# Issue with POST values in jQuery dialog

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<form>
    <input type='submit' name='btn1' value='btn1' onclick='javascript:return test()' />
</form>
```

---

```
function test(){
    $('#testDiv').dialog('open');
}
```

Dialog have 2 buttons 'OK' & 'cancel'

On the 'OK' button I have written `.submit()` which is working fine.

But the issue is when values are posted to .php file `$_POST['btn1']` is not set. Which would have been set if there is no function called on `OnClick` event and the submit button had been directly triggered.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what's the idea behind this? This is normal behavior, you could have trigger `submit` somewhere outside, not clicking the button.

Comment: Let's see your `submit` code as well.

Comment: Can you post the html of the form with id=formId and also that of the #testDiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, if you do manual jQuery submit , i.e) by calling    $("#formid").submit(); your submit button will not present in POST values but all other values will present.

This Issue I have noticed while am working on jquery Ajax captcha.

You can confirm that by putting one or two hidden values and check your POST values.

Answer (score 0):

put some value in your submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="... do whatever"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but can try this: onclick="test()" (remove the return keyword.